# Hiscore vs Highscore

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

Which of these are correct?

- Hiscore
- Hi-score
- Highscore
- High-score

I have seen all except the last being used.

Comment: They are all correct, depending on how you define correct. What context do you want to check if they are correct for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could argue that they are all correct in modern usage. "Hi" is often substituted for "high" in certain (video game) contexts; similarly, "Lo" for "low". This usage is so pervasive these days as to be acceptable now IMHO.

If you wanted to be a pedant, I'd plump for "high-score", or even "highest score".

Answer (score 8):

I have no problem with *Hi-score* or *High-score*, although I don't see the need for a hyphen.

As for *Highscore*, I don't see the need to eliminate the space and mash it together as one word (unless it's a variable name or something, in which case the rules of standard English hardly apply anyway).

I would avoid *Hiscore*, however.  At first glance, it's too easy to erroneously parse as *his core* instead of *hi score*.

Finally, if you did break it into two words, you might want to use title case (i.e., High Score), depending on the context.

Comment: _Hi-score_ would need a hyphen to avoid confusion between _hi-score_, and _his-core_. If you write _hifi_, there would not be any confusion, thought.

Comment: I would argue that High Score is the best to use. I have nothing againt Highscore, but I guess that combining them together is normally not the correct English way of spelling it.